# JavaScript: quickly search for interval in array

Tags: javascript, binary-search

A sorted array of numbers is given.

The idea is that for any given number, the code needs to find the two enclosing indices in the array such that:

```
array[a] <= query <= array[b]
```

For example, if the given array is `[1, 20, 56, 200]` and the number is `67`, then `56 <= 67 <= 200` so the result is `[2, 3]`.

I did a small test with a simple O(n) loop and two variants of a binary search, and surprisingly the loop was much faster for a low n (~0-100?).
The test can be accessed here: http://jsperf.com/array-search-test/5

Is there a way to get something more optimized than those binary searches? this function runs thousands and tens of thousands times per second.

Comment: `something more optimized than those binary searches` [NO](http://i1.kym-cdn.com/photos/images/newsfeed/000/232/114/e39.png)

Comment: Why do you need to run the binary search function `thousands and tens of thousands times per second`? Surely there is a different approach?

Comment: javascript's overhead is quite heavy. O(n) will win in all case for a low n because of this. You must do it linearly for a low n, and even for a high n, you have to do the latest steps of the search in a linear fashion (just like quicksort, for instance, stops recursion when a 8-sized partition  is encountered to use another sort even when coded in asm).

Comment: The different approach is to keep state outside of this function (e.g. what the indices were last time, and a direct check if you passed them yet), but I would prefer to not have state outside of this function.

Answer (score 1):

> I did a small test with a simple O(n) loop and two variants of a binary search, and surprisingly the loop was much faster for a low n (~0-100?). The test can be accessed here: http://jsperf.com/array-search-test/2

First off, that’s how big-O works. In your binary search, there are many operations; sequential array access is relatively few.

But that’s not entirely what’s happening here. Your benchmarks don’t do what they claim.

In the benchmark labelled “O(n), n=50”, for example, n is still worst-case-1000. You’re just running 50 searches. However, since the tenth element of the array is 50, it’ll only ever do 50 comparisons. This isn’t true of the following binary searches; they both start at element 500. Hardly fair!

Make a few arrays.

Comment: @minitech I think it would be more representative to use the same size array but instead look up x indices with a set of randomly chosen numbers as a goal. So you look up 50 indices in a set of 5000 numbers, then 500 indices etc. You should randomize these indices, because otherwise you will be basically just brute force summing up all probabilities for these cases instead of having a realistic average case http://jsperf.com/array-search-test/9 Then suddenly binary search is over 10 times faster.

Comment: Actually, it does make a lot of sense to test for different size arrays since the whole O(n) idea is based on the size of your data. But you should not sum up the results for every index from 0 to n. That's not a realistic result.

Comment: While it's probably not a very good test for the general case, it's actually what my code does. There's a timer going from 0 to N and each time I query the array.

Answer (score 1):

> I did a small test with a simple O(n) loop and two variants of a binary search, and surprisingly the loop was much faster for a low n (~0-100?). The test can be accessed here: http://jsperf.com/array-search-test/2

Sure, binary search has a large overhead compared to the much smaller loop body of the straightforward iteration.

What the [big O notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation) describes "*the limiting behavior* [upper bound] *of a function when the argument tends towards a particular value or infinity*" and does not provide any evidence to compare two runs of particular implementations.

However, as @minitech noticed, your test case is flawed, and even at n=50 the binary search is already faster than the linear one. [Here's an updated example](http://jsperf.com/array-search-test/8), which also tests n=5 (where linear search is indeed faster) and nicely depicts the expected `O(n)` vs `O(log N)` difference in the graphs (though with exponential growth of the test data (5*10<sup>n</sup>) the graphs are exponential vs linear).

> Is there a way to get something more optimized than those binary searches?

You might have a look at [interpolation search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpolation_search).

> this function runs thousands and tens of thousands times per second.

Why that? You might even better build a lookup table of your values then.

Comment: I thought about building a look up table, but I don't really like the memory usage that might take. I have many of these time-line arrays.

Comment: Well, it's usually always performance vs memory usage. But still, please describe your actual usecase more specifically, there might be much better solutions than running a search tenthousand times a second.

Comment: ...for example, you could do a handful of the searches concurrently in a single pass through the loop rather than doing a full search each time

Comment: This is used for 3D animation. The searches look for the correct keyframes to use from a given timeline. Every search is actually using a different timeline, and the timelines don't necessarily have the same keys (a timeline is basically an array of time=>data mapping that holds stuff like translation/rotation/scaling data, in case you are not related to the 3D scene)

Comment: But for animation, you don't have to search at all, you just are running linear through the time and through the array? If there are multiple timelines active, just each of them should have its own array (most easy) or its own index in the large array.

Comment: The array is sparse, it holds only the important animation keys (= keyframes), and the end result needs the two keys that surround a specific frame to do some sort of (usually linear) interpolation between them. In other words, right now there is an animation timer that grows each frame, and then the array that holds only the key frames is checked to see what two keys are relevant to the current animation frame.

Comment: Sure, but the frames are "iterated" (shown) in linear sequence only?! Whether the keyframes array is sparse or not does not matter, the sequence of the "surrounding keyframes" is linear as well even though the index might be different from the frame number. You might ask a new question with the code you're currently using, I'd be happy to help you there, but these comments are growing a little OT.

Comment: I assume you are suggesting to hold the current keyframe index, and do a simple check of array[index + 1]>=currentFrame, right? I will probably do this, but I preferred something that wont make me keep track of yet more state. This also doesn't work for things that are created at arbitrary points in time (e.g. particles), but it should still boost performance.

Comment: Yes, exactly, it would be such simple (and had `O(1)` performance). Keeping track of the state of your animation is necessary. You really should ask a more specific question about that algorithm, and explain there why it would not work for particles.

Comment: The particles can be spawned at any time, so their starting state needs to be queried (it can't be simply initialized to 0). But most of the queries don't come from particles, so this is still fine, it just means I need two separate ways to get data - with a given index (O(1)) or without one (binary search).